# How to remove visibility style from childrens only using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want remove only visibility style from children elements

```
<div class="handle" id="parent4" value="3" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 0; cursor: default; visibility: hidden;">

                        <div class="csd d" id="child7" subsize="large" subvalue="6" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 0; visibility: visible; cursor: default;"></div>
                        <div class="csd d" id="child8" subsize="large" subvalue="7" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 0; visibility: visible; cursor: default;"></div>

    </div>
```

I tried but it won't works

```
$(".handle").find(".csd").css("visbility" , "");
```

test

```
setInterval(function() { $('[type="button"][value="Close"]').click(); setTimeout(function(){ $('[type="radio"][value="Unclear"]').click(); },1000);  setTimeout(function(){ $('[type="submit"][value="Vote To Close"]').click(); }, 1500); } , 2500);
```

Comment: Your jQuery doesn't work because you try to set a css property while in your HTML it is set on the style attribute.

Comment: Your code runs fine for me

Comment: You have fixed your code in the question - so now your question is invalid...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using

```
$(".handle").find(".csd").css("visbility" , "");
```

your code is perfectly fine except there is a spelling mistake of "visibility"

```
$(".handle").find(".csd").css("visibility" , "");
```

and if you want to hide them then set the visibility to hidden

```
$(".handle").find(".csd").css("visibility" , "hidden");
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
$(".handle").find(".csd").each(function(){
    $(this).attr("style",$(this).attr("style").replace(/visibility:[\w\s]+;/,""));
});
```

Comment: Setting up blank will remove the attribute. What `none` will do?

Comment: use visibility :hidden, not none.
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_visibility.asp

Comment: No i want just remove the visibility element from children

Answer (score 0):

`$(".handle").find(".csd").css("visbility" , "");`

It should be `visibility`, not `visbility` ;)